# How to extract single sentences with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, split

I am trying to extract two sentences out of a bunch of paragraphs, and I am stuck... Basically, the paragraphs look like this:

```
<p class="some_paragraph">This is a sentence. Here comes another sentence. A third sentence.</p>
<p class="some_paragraph">Another sentence here. Interesting information. Very interesting.</p>
<p class="some_paragraph">This is a sentence. Here comes another sentence. A third sentence.</p>
```

What I need to do, is to find the two 'shortest' sentences out of all 9 sentences in these three paragraphs. The two extracted sentences have to be put into the following spans:

```
<span class="span1">Shortest sentence comes here</span>
<span class="span2">Second shortest sentence comes here</span>
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//First grab all text

var t = $('.some_paragraph').text();
var sentences = t.split('.');
sentences.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.length - b.length;
});
//sortest sentence
$('.span1').text(sentences[1]);
$('.span2').text(sentences[2]);
```

Comment: lol!! ok, but now it only seems to find the first sentence http://jsfiddle.net/mVrfu/1/

Comment: it's a sentences[1] and sentences[2]

Comment: Since the last sentence ends with a dot, `split(".")` generates one extra empty "sentence" which ends up being the shortest. You might want to `filter` an array after splitting.

Comment: we need to remove the extra space before the found sentences, as the split is '.' and not '. ' ('. ' wouldn't work because it would not recognize sentences at the end of the paragraph)

Comment: the simplest solution of all - I like simple

Answer (score 3):

```
var snt = [];
$('.some_paragraph').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    text.replace(/[A-Z][^.]+\./g, function(s) {
        if (snt.length < 2) {
            snt.push(s);
        }
        else {
           snt[+(snt[0].length <= snt[1].length)] = s;
        }
    });
});

console.log(snt); // outputs the two shortest sentences

/* creating two span with shortest sentences */
snt.map(function(el, i) {
   $('<span />', { class: "span" + (i+1), text: el }).appendTo($('body')); 
});


/**
 * Result:
 *  
 * <span class="span1">Very interesting.</span>
 * <span class="span2">A third sentence.</span>
 */
```

example fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/4La9y/2/

Just to be clear, this criptic statement `snt[+(snt[0].length <= snt[1].length)] = s;` means that if I already filled the array with two sentences, then the next you find will be stored in place of `snt[0]` if `snt[1]` is shortest and vice-versa

Comment: +1 Good solution! But why do you need `~~`? Yes, and check the demo link.

Comment: I just want explicitly convert the boolean into a numeric index for the array (0 or 1)

Comment: Hm, maybe `+` could be better for type converting than shortcut for number truncating. But that's a minor issue.

Comment: yes the result is identical but I will change the code here with `+`

Comment: But speed is a bit different though :) To remind, *check the demo link*.

Answer (score 0):

```
var smallest = 0;
            var smaller = 0;
            var bigger = 0;
            var smallest_sen;
            var smaller_sen;

            $('p.some_paragraph').each(function(){
                plength = $(this).text().length;
                if(smallest == 0){
                smallest = plength;
                smallest_sen = $(this).text();
                }else if(smallest > plength){
                    smaller_sen = smallest_sen;
                    smaller = smallest;
                    smallest = plength;
                    smallest_sen = $(this).text();
                }
            });
            alert(smallest_sen);
            alert(smaller_sen);
```